# Grass in my bulb garden

Tags: weed-control, bulbs

Every year I weed around my bulbs which is full of grass, dandelions & thistle. By the time I get done weeding it all, it’s time to start weeding all over again & my back can’t take it anymore. I’ve tried ground cover, I’ve tried news paper, cardboard, mulch.... all of which is supposed to kill the roots because it can’t get the sun light to the roots. None of these have worked. Is there anything I can do or use or spray my bulb flower beds without harming the plants/bulbs so that I don’t have grass growing all summer that’s as high as by flowers? I’d like to enjoy my beautiful flowers not spend every waking hour weeding. Please help.

Comment: What kind of bulbs and weeds, even if you plant late tulips they are done by June-ish and the bed is clear for a major hoe down

Comment: weeds are slang for "plants growing where they're not desired"

Comment: What kind of grass - lawn grass? quackgrass? crab grass? Is the bed edged - if so, with what?